# express.js + stylus: Automatic stylus compiling doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

I am running express.js 3.4.0 with stylus 0.37.0 I am trying to get express and stylus work together so when I request a css file which is actually a stylus file somewhere else, express triggers stylus to compile it and then serve it (pretty standard I guess as I see it working in many tutorials).

My file structure:

```
myApp
  resources
    stylus
      style.styl
  public
    css
```

My app.js (only relevant lines):

```
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + "/resources/stylus",
    dest: __dirname + "/public/css",
    debug: true,
    force: true,
}));
```

From what I read, requesting `/static/css/style.css` should lead to express generating this file from `resources/stylus/style.styl` and then serving it. This does not work. What works is if I request the file `/style.css` the file `/public/css/style.css` is correctly generated, but I get a 404 nonetheless. Afterwards, I can request it through `/static/css/style.css` as it exists physically now.

Can somebody suggest any steps to fix this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the compiling to work, the directory that you're serving from must also exist in the source directory. Since `style.styl` is in the root of the source, it is also in the root for `GET` requests. In resources, rename `stylus` to `css`, and change your configuration to look like this:

```
app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/resources',
  dest: __dirname + '/public',
  debug: true,
  force: true
}));
```

Now when you `GET /css/style.css`, it will compile the stylesheets. Graphically, this is how compiling is structured:

```
/resources/style.styl       -->   /public/style.css
/resources/css/style.styl   -->   /public/css/style.css
```

Then, another issue comes up. You want to serve `/public` with `/static`.

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You will have to change that line to:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public/static'));
```

The solution to this would be to structure your application like this:

```
myApp
├─┬ public
│ └─┬ static
│   └── css
└─┬ resources
  └─┬ static
    └─┬ css
      └── style.styl
```

Now, when you `GET /static/css/style.css`, the stylesheets will be compiled from location `/resources/static/css/style.styl`.

As a result with the file tree shown above and this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public/static'));
app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/resources/',
  dest: __dirname + '/public/',
  debug: true,
  force: true,
}));
```

On first load `/static/css/style.css` will 404 but on second load the stylesheets will be there.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem, but only after copying my node app to Windows. On Linux, it worked both ways for some reason. Thanks for the detailled explanation.

Comment: It's a very weird system. I would expect that having `src: 'assets/css'` would compile `assets/css/xyz.css` but instead it requires `src: 'assets'` and automatically resolves to `/css`. Crazy.

Comment: I think this is a bug.  I've sent in a PR to make the middleware work the way you think on windows.  Fancy workaround though! https://github.com/stylus/stylus/pull/2029

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18806103/6405900) of [hexacyanide](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1380918/hexacyanide), I added path.join to make sure it works on any os ( for instance, on windows sometimes it doesn't work when not using the correct path seperator ).

The code ends up looking like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public/static'));
app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'resources'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  debug: true,
  force: true,
}));
```

The path module should add the correct path seperator ( '/' or '\' ) according to the os.